# TriangleMesh - Backside faces are visible

Tags: java, javafx-8, javafx-3d

Good Day! I have the following issue. The graphic model is not displayed correctly: some backside faces of the model that should be hidden by the frontside remain visible. Here are some exmples to clarify: (isometry)[image]

(issue)

[image]

This issue comes out especially notable when applying light and material. So the the question is how this can be solved for JavaFX?

UPD:

```
public class VertexTest extends Application {

    PerspectiveCamera camera;
    Cam cam = new Cam();
    double mouseOldX, mouseOldY, mousePosX, mousePosY, mouseDeltaX, mouseDeltaY;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        TriangleMesh mesh = new Shape3DRectangle(100, 100, 100);
        MeshView view = new MeshView(mesh);
        view.setDrawMode(DrawMode.LINE);
        view.setMaterial(new PhongMaterial(Color.RED));

        cam.getChildren().add(view);

        Scene scene = new Scene(cam, 1000, 1000, true);

        addEvents(view, scene);

        camera = new PerspectiveCamera();
        camera.setTranslateX(-500);
        camera.setTranslateY(-500);
        camera.setTranslateZ(1000);


        scene.setCamera(camera);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private void addEvents(MeshView view, Scene s) {

        s.setOnMouseDragged(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            public void handle(MouseEvent me) {
                mouseOldX = mousePosX;
                mouseOldY = mousePosY;
                mousePosX = me.getX();
                mousePosY = me.getY();
                mouseDeltaX = mousePosX - mouseOldX;
                mouseDeltaY = mousePosY - mouseOldY;
                cam.ry.setAngle(cam.ry.getAngle() - mouseDeltaX);
                cam.rx.setAngle(cam.rx.getAngle() + mouseDeltaY);
            }
        });
    }

    class Cam extends Group {
        Translate t = new Translate();
        Translate p = new Translate();
        Translate ip = new Translate();
        Rotate rx = new Rotate();
        {
            rx.setAxis(Rotate.X_AXIS);
        }
        Rotate ry = new Rotate();
        {
            ry.setAxis(Rotate.Y_AXIS);
        }
        Rotate rz = new Rotate();
        {
            rz.setAxis(Rotate.Z_AXIS);
        }
        Scale s = new Scale();

        public Cam() {
            super();
            getTransforms().addAll(t, p, rx, rz, ry, s, ip);
        }
    }



    public class Shape3DRectangle extends TriangleMesh {

        public Shape3DRectangle(float Width, float Height, float deep) {

            this.getPoints().setAll(-Width / 2, Height / 2, deep / 2, // idx p0
                    Width / 2, Height / 2, deep / 2, // idx p1
                    -Width / 2, -Height / 2, deep / 2, // idx p2
                    Width / 2, -Height / 2, deep / 2, // idx p3
                    -Width / 2, Height / 2, -deep / 2, // idx p4
                    Width / 2, Height / 2, -deep / 2, // idx p5
                    -Width / 2, -Height / 2, -deep / 2, // idx p6
                    Width, -Height / 2, -deep / 2 // idx p7
            );

            this.getTexCoords().addAll(0.0f, 0.0f);

            this.getFaces().addAll(5, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0 // P5,T1 ,P4,T0 ,P0,T3
                    , 5, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0 // P5,T1 ,P0,T3 ,P1,T4
                    , 0, 0, 4, 0, 6, 0 // P0,T3 ,P4,T2 ,P6,T7
                    , 0, 0, 6, 0, 2, 0 // P0,T3 ,P6,T7 ,P2,T8
                    , 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0 // P1,T4 ,P0,T3 ,P2,T8
                    , 1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0 // P1,T4 ,P2,T8 ,P3,T9
                    , 5, 0, 1, 0, 3, 0 // P5,T5 ,P1,T4 ,P3,T9
                    , 5, 0, 3, 0, 7, 0 // P5,T5 ,P3,T9 ,P7,T10
                    , 4, 0, 5, 0, 7, 0 // P4,T6 ,P5,T5 ,P7,T10
                    , 4, 0, 7, 0, 6, 0 // P4,T6 ,P7,T10 ,P6,T11
                    , 3, 0, 2, 0, 6, 0 // P3,T9 ,P2,T8 ,P6,T12
                    , 3, 0, 6, 0, 7, 0 // P3,T9 ,P6,T12 ,P7,T13
            );
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: with no code the only thing I can say is : ***good luck with that***

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpa thanks for wishes )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been playing around with your sample, and I think I've found out the reason of your issues.

First, I checked the winding of the faces. All of them are counter-clockwise, so all their normals go outwards, as they should be.

Then I modified other vertices instead of the last one. In some cases there were no issues, in others, the issue was still there.

Basically, the issue happens when there are "concave" surfaces, meaning that two faces have normals that will cross. And it doesn't happen when all the surfaces are "convex", meaning that their normals point outwards and won't cross.

This is a clear image of both type of meshes taken from [here](http://www.rustycode.com/tutorials/convex.html):

[image]

Back to your sample, you are defining a concave mesh:

[image: issue]

But if instead of modifying vertex #7, we make the #5 larger, we have a convex mesh, with no rendering issues:

[image: no issue]

Obviously, while this fix the rendering problem, it changes your initial shape.

If you want to keep your initial geometry, the other possible solution is changing the faces, so you don't have any concave areas.

Let's have a look at the faces 5-1-3 and 5-3-7, and let's say we want to move now the vertex #1.

If we keep your triangles, face 5-1-3 and 5-3-7 will define a concave surface to be render (their normals will cross), while if we change those triangles to 5-1-7 and 1-3-7, then the surface will be convex (their normals won't cross):

[image: normals]

Back to your initial shape, this change in those two faces will solve the rendering issues.

[image: Solved]

While the vertices are the same, the geometry is a little bit difference. So it requires some refinement (more elements). Adding those elements should be done keeping in mind this convex concept. The problem is not trivial, though, as you can see [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/53142/decomposing-a-concave-mesh-into-a-set-of-convex-meshes).

Comment: I want to say thank you for all your answers related to JavaFx technology. Unfortunately objects with which I need to work consist of several-million faces and have complex shapes. The most important thing is that I found the right direction  in your reply and for this special thank you.

Comment: My pleasure, glad to be of any help. I discovered this issue based on your question and sample code, I didn't think of it before nor I found it elsewhere. Probably it should be mentioned in the documentation...

Answer (score 1):

Nice analysis by Jose but it looks to me as if the OP has just forgotten to divide the Width by 2 in this line of his code.

```
Width, -Height / 2, -deep / 2 // idx p7
```

should be

```
Width / 2, -Height / 2, -deep / 2 // idx p7
```

The class is called Shape3DRectangle but with this mistake
the geometry is not rectangular anymore.

Comment: Maybe it was a typo, but the OP clearly asked for the backside faces issue. It is a possible scenario where you have a box and you start distorting its vertex creating other 3D shapes, not always uniform and convex.

Comment: mipa @José Pereda is right. Class name comes from the previous test ... My bad...

Answer (score 0):

You can set the cullFaceProperty for every Shape3D. I guess that is what you need but I am not sure whether I understood your question precisely.

[Shape3D#cullFaceProperty](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/shape/Shape3D.html#cullFaceProperty)